# Solution to the Diophantine Equation $n^2+n=2(m^2+m)$

Tags: diophantine-equations

The other day, a friend asked if it is possible to halve a triangular number and be left with another triangular number (in fact, she asked a more geometric question, about cutting an equilateral triangle of dots in half, but it reduced to this.) Obviously, this reduces to finding natural number solutions to the following Diophantine equation:
$$
n^2+n = 2(m^2+m)
$$
A trivial solution is $n=3$, $m=2$, and numerical experiments found half a dozen more. However, I'm curious if there's a more general solution. With my applied-math background, I have always been terrified by such problems. Is it possible to find an explicit solution for the $m, n$ pairs which make this work? How do you go about tackling problems like this?

Thanks

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1501010_sum_of_two_consecutive_squares_equals_difference_of_two_cons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers satisfying
$$n^2+n=2(m^2+m),$$
then $x:=2n+1$ and $y:=2m+1$ are positive integers satisfying
$$x^2-2y^2=-1.$$
This equation is know as [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) with $n=2$. Its solutions have been studied since ancient times, and are known as [Pell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number). There are many characterizations of the solutions, and the linked Wikipedia pages give an excellent exposition that I won't reproduce here.

Answer (score 2):

With $w = 2n+1$  and $v=2m+1$ I got 
$$  w^2 - 2 v^2 = -1.  $$
The trace is six so we get
$$ w_{j+2} = 6 w_{j+1} - w_j \; , \; $$
$$ v_{j+2} = 6 v_{j+1} - v_j \; . \; $$

The $w$ start
$$ 1, 7, 41, 239, 1393  $$
then your
$$ n = \frac{w-1}{2}  $$ begin
$$ n= 0, 3, 20, 119, 696, 4059, 23660, 137903, 803760, 4684659, ...  $$  with 
$$ n_{j+2} = 6 n_{j+1} - n_j + 2 \; . \; $$

The $v$ start
$$ 1, 5, 29, 169, 985   $$
then your
$$ m = \frac{v-1}{2}  $$ begin
$$ m= 0, 2, 14, 84, 492, 2870, 16730, 97512, 568344, 3312554, ...  $$  with 
$$ m_{j+2} = 6 m_{j+1} - m_j + 2 \; . \; $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   4
    2   3
  Automorphism backwards:  
    3   -4
    -2   3

  3^2 - 2 2^2 = 1

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = -1 =   -1 *  1 

Wed Feb 13 13:52:31 PST 2019

w:  1  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  7  v:  5
w:  41  v:  29
w:  239  v:  169
w:  1393  v:  985
w:  8119  v:  5741
w:  47321  v:  33461
w:  275807  v:  195025
w:  1607521  v:  1136689
w:  9369319  v:  6625109

Wed Feb 13 13:52:56 PST 2019

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = -1 =   -1 *  1 

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is a [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), and that the solutions of this particular one are well understood.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *"The trace is six..."*?

Comment: @Servaes an (oriented) automorphism of an integral quadratic form is a square matrix $P,$ nonsingular and integral, with $P^T H P = H,$ while $H$ is the Hessian matrix of the form. In two variables, the group is generated by a single matrix (and its inverse). In this case a column vector Pell type solution $X$ is taken to another by $X \mapsto PX.$ In turn, Cayley-Hamilton returns linear recurrences for each element of $X$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the convergents to $\sqrt 2$
$$\frac 11,\frac 32,\frac 75, \frac {17}{12}, \frac {41}{29}\ldots$$
If we write them as $\frac {a_n}{b_n}$ the recurrence is 
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+2b_n\\b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$$
The cross products of two neighboring fractions differ by $1$ and can be your $m,m+1$, so $2\cdot 7=14, 3\cdot 5=15, \frac 12\cdot 14 \cdot 15=105$.  The product of the numerators will be either your $n$ or $n+1$, so $3\cdot 7=21, \frac 12\cdot 20 \cdot 21=210=2\cdot 105$.  It will be $n+1$ if the first fraction is greater than $\sqrt 2$ and $n$ if the first fraction is less than $\sqrt 2$.  The fractions alternate greater and less.

All these assertions can be proven by using the recurrence.  I have not proven that there are no more solutions, but I believe it to be true.